# python selenium log number of times page refreshes

Tags: python, selenium

I want to know if there is any way to log the number of times my page has refreshed in command prompt when running.

want it to tell me the number of times it has refreshed. Refresh is located between while true: and continue. thanks

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get(link)

while True:
    size = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='atg_store_picker']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span[2]/a[4]")
    if len(size) <= 0:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print "PAGE NOT LIVE"
        driver.refresh()
        continue

    else:`enter code here`
        print 'LIVE!!!!'
        break
```

Comment: you need a variable with a higher scope for this. something like `count += 1; print("%d refreshes" % count)`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre could you show me an example please. you could edit the  code how every u want. thanks!

Comment: what I don't understand is when and by what the code you posted is called. You should edit your post to show the caller too. I may be able to help then.

Comment: how about if i want to count the loop? its basically the same thing @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: solved my own problem @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Answer (score 1):

the answer to my question was very simple...

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get(link)
count = 0
while True:
    size = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='atg_store_picker']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span[2]/a[4]")
    if len(size) <= 0:
        count +=1
        print 'Refresh Count:', count
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.refresh()
        continue

    else:
        print 'LIVE!!!!'
        break
```